# Survey Monkey Webhook

Tags: node.js, webhooks, surveymonkey

After creating the webhook, when I fill in a form it sends a POST request to my API, but the body comes empty.

I can not find anything on the internet, the SM documentation leaves much to be desired.

My API

```
async testWebhook({ request, response }) {
   console.log('request.body', request.body)
   response.status(200).send()
   return
}
```

What can it be?

Answer (score 5):

I found an answer if your app is running on Express.js

The Survey Monkey Webhook POST declares a header 'application/vnd.surveymonkey.response.v1+json'

If you don't handle this in Express, the request.body object will be empty.

You can use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) and define the header:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    type: 'application/vnd.surveymonkey.response.v1+json'
}));
```

See documentation here - [body-parser types](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#type)

I should also mention that when I created my Webhook with Survey Monkey, I did include 'content-type' but it wasn't until I added this extra configuration in my app that it started showing me POST data.

Example Webhook creation:

```
{
    "name": "My Survey Completed Webhook",
    "event_type": "response_completed",
    "object_type": "survey",
    "object_ids": ["1234"],
    "subscription_url": "https://APP_URL/survey-responses",
    "content_type": "application/json"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The body should have a JSON with a body similar to the example. One possible issue is that the webhook from SurveyMonkey sends the body with a custom content type header, something like `application/vnd.surveymonkey.survey.v1` which may not be playing nice with your server.

I'm not sure if it's documented but you can specify `application/json` as your content type by including that in the body when you're creating a webhook:

```
POST /v3/webhooks
{
  ...
  "content_type": "application/json"
}
```

Which may make it work without any changes to your body parser settings in your server.